# A loader on Splash Screen in Phonegap 5.4

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

I have just started creating an app in phonegap 5.4.1(the latest one) using CLI, phonegap create unishkuri --id "com.abp.unishkuri" --name "unishkuri"
and it has been created successfully under User. In the folder structure I found hooks,platforms,plugins,www and config.xml. platforms and plugins are empty while under www ---> css,img,js,res,spec,icon.png,index.html,spec.html are there. 
I can add a splash screen from config.xml file.
Now, my question is if I want to add a custom loader on splash screen, how will it be possible. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of the splash screen plugin (3.1.0), you can add a spinner adding this line to the config.xml

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
```

But you can't customize it without changing the native code of the plugin

Comment: hey thanks for your reply... Do i need to install splash screen plugin or we can change splash screen from config.xml also.

Comment: You have  to install the splash screen plugin